# python 3.2.5 grid sticky/weight not working

Tags: python, tkinter

Below is a simple illustration of the problem. It consists of a grid layout where I've placed a button widget in `row 0` and a text widget in `row 1`.

What I want is for the text widget in `row 1` to expand with the form while keeping the top of the text widget anchored NW (row 0 not expanding). The problem is that the horizontal(column expands correctly, but the text widget row does not. If I get rid of the button the text widget expands correctly. Also the original form I've put together is more involved and is best served using a grid. So basically using pack isn't a solution. Any help would be appreciated.

```
################################################

from tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent

        self.initGui()

    # ##################################################################
    # Initialize GUI widgets    
    def initGui(self):
        self.parent.title("Test Grid")
        self.parent.resizable(width=TRUE, height=TRUE)
        self.grid(sticky=W+E+N+S, padx=20, pady=20)
        self.parent.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.parent.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

        # Add a button to row 0
        self.btn = Button(self, text="Button", width=20)
        self.btn.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=(0,10),pady=(0,10), sticky=N+W)

        # Add a text box and v-scrollbar to row 1
        self.txtOut = Text(self, width=80, height=20)
        self.scrOut = Scrollbar(self)
        self.txtOut.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=(0,18),sticky=N+E+S+W)
        self.scrOut.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=N+S+E)
        self.scrOut.config(command=self.txtOut.yview)
        self.txtOut.config(yscrollcommand=self.scrOut.set)
        print(self.grid_size())

def main():
    root = Tk()
    app = Application(parent=root)   
    app.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: As [pointed by Bryan](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23205602), there is a typo when you grid application in root. To hunt down this kind of geometry management bug, you can colorize your widget: `root["bg"] = "red"; app["bg"] = "blue"` to identify how each widget behave.

Comment: The self.parent is not necessary and does nothing to change the code. If I remove those two statements, does that remove the typo to which you are referring?

Comment: Bryan said *The core problem is that you are putting the application frame in row 0 (zero), but you are giving row 1 (one) a weight of 1 (one)*, thus replacing `self.parent.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)` by `self.parent.rowconfigure(` **0** `, weight=1)` do the job.

Answer (score 1):

There's a case where using `pack` probably is a solution. It won't cause any conflicts if you pack the instance of the Frame (`Application`) inside the root window, then grid widgets inside that frame. It'll cut down on the headache of all the rowconfigure and columnconfigure methods and just makes more sense to me.

```
def initGui(self):
    self.parent.title("Test Grid")
    self.parent.resizable(width=TRUE, height=TRUE)

    self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1, padx=20, pady=20)
    self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
```

Comment: Perfect, that solved it. I obviously don't understand the hierarchy. I thought the grid or pack was contained within the application frame. Although I don't completely have a good picture of what your change did, I'm guessing that your change effectively wrapped the application frame with a pack and then inside the frame wrapped the widgets with a grid? I didn't think you could mix the two, although I guess the frame provides an adequate separation boundary.

Comment: @user3557730, the `Application` class is a subclass of the Frame widget. You pack the `Application` frame into the root window, then you can work within that Frame to pack or grid other widgets. Every time you make a Frame, or "parent", you can change the geometry manager without any conflicts. You'll only have a conflict if you use pack and grid within the same parent widget.

Answer (score 1):

The core problem is that you are putting the application frame in row 0 (zero), but you are giving row 1 (one) a weight of 1 (one). That is why the text widget doesn't expand when you resize the window.

This is really hard to see because you mix grid commands of a widget in its parent, along with its own children widgets. It makes it hard to quickly scan the code to see what the layout options are, because you can't assume all of the grid, pack or place commands only affect child widgets.

Another minor problem with your code is that you've put the text widget and scrollbar in the same column.

Here's how I would change the code: remove the `self.grid` and `self.parent.*configure` commands from `initGui`. Then, use pack to add the application frame to the root window at the point where it's created. Also, move the scrollbar to column 1.

```
class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent

        self.initGui()

    # ##################################################################
    # Initialize GUI widgets    
    def initGui(self):
        self.parent.title("Test Grid")
        self.parent.resizable(width=TRUE, height=TRUE)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

        # Add a button to row 0
        self.btn = Button(self, text="Button", width=20)
        self.btn.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=(0,10),pady=(0,10), sticky=N+W)

        # Add a text box and v-scrollbar to row 1
        self.txtOut = Text(self, width=80, height=20)
        self.scrOut = Scrollbar(self)
        self.txtOut.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=(0,18),sticky=N+E+S+W)
        self.scrOut.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky=N+S)
        self.scrOut.config(command=self.txtOut.yview)
        self.txtOut.config(yscrollcommand=self.scrOut.set)
        print(self.grid_size())

def main():
    root = Tk()
    app = Application(parent=root)   
    app.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    app.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The code shown is only a simplified of the final GUI. The final GUI contains 14 widgets, which out of all the layouts works best using a grid. I tried to use pack because but I could find no way to create the grid equivalent that I wanted using pack. The approach shown does everything I want except expand the text widget vertically with the main form. At the moment I have the height fixed, but would prefer to allow the user to expand the height if desired.

Comment: @user3557730: I don't quite understand what you wrote. My solution expands the text widget vertically. The magic isn't in using pack, that just required two fewer lines. You could just as easily use grid and do what I suggest -- make sure you give a weight to the proper row.

Comment: Sorry about the broken response. It was posted accidentally. Your solution worked perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you passing padx as tuple rather than an integer?? & what does this means??

Comment: @ShambhavAgrawal: when passing a tuple, the first value is the padding to apply to the left, and the second value is the padding to apply to the right.

Comment: @BryanOakley that sounds great. Thank you so much. Do you have any idea about how can we provide height & width in cm or mm ( other than pixels [ which is by default ] )?

Comment: @ShambhavAgrawal: you can use the letter "c" for centimeters, "i" for inches, "m" for millimeters, and "p" for printers points (eg: padx="2c"). Though, these measurements depend on the scaling factor being set properly which is often not the case.